# How can print compress data flow content in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Attribute Log Message for logging but if data is compress as gzip log not message readable. How  can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `LogAttribute` processor will print whatever the flowfile attribute(s) and content (if desired) contain. If the data is compressed, you will first need to uncompress it with the `CompressContent` processor to have it print in a human-readable form.